# How is called 1D and 2D analogy to saddle point

Tags: analysis, terminology, potential-theory

Consider n-dimensional function with multiple local minima (e.g. http://ac6la.com/aeopt5.png). There exist some [basins of attraction](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Basin_of_attraction) for which particle fall to one or the other minimum. Boundary between two such basins has some properties of saddle point ( along some direction first derivative is zero, and second derivative negative )

Is there any good mathematical term for this line (in 2D; or surface in 3D) ?

I was considering *separatrix* used in context of differential equations but that is probably something a bit different.

other therms - *inflection  line*, *critical line*, *saddle line*

even more illustrative image:

http://journal.media-culture.org.au/files/journals/1/articles/716/supp/716-2834-1-SP.jpg
(I want to know which term to use for the dashed line which separates the two basins)